# Changing activation function of a keras layer w/o replacing whole layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to change the activation function of the last layer of a keras model without replacing the whole layer. In this case, only the softmax function

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
import numpy as np

model = load_model(model_path)  # Load any model
img = load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
img = img_to_array(img)
print(model.predict(img))
```

My output:

```
array([[1.53172877e-07, 7.13159451e-08, 6.18941920e-09, 8.52070968e-07,
    1.25813088e-07, 9.98970985e-01, 1.48254022e-08, 6.09538893e-06,
    1.16236095e-07, 3.91888688e-10, 6.29304608e-08, 1.79565995e-09,
    1.75571788e-08, 1.02110009e-03, 2.14380114e-09, 9.54465733e-08,
    1.05938483e-07, 2.20544337e-07]], dtype=float32)
```

Then I do this to change the activation:

```
model.layers[-1].activation = custom_softmax
print(model.predict(test_img))
```

and the output I got is exactly the same. Any ideas how to fix? Thanks!

You could try to use the `custom_softmax` below:

```
def custom_softmax(x, axis=-1):
"""Softmax activation function.
# Arguments
    x : Tensor.
    axis: Integer, axis along which the softmax normalization is applied.
# Returns
    Tensor, output of softmax transformation.
# Raises
    ValueError: In case `dim(x) == 1`.
"""
ndim = K.ndim(x)
if ndim >= 2:
    return K.zeros_like(x)
else:
    raise ValueError('Cannot apply softmax to a tensor that is 1D')
```

Comment: Are you sure the original model doesn't also already end with a softmax? Those existing outputs are already very close to summing up to `1` (they add up to `1.00000002685`)

Comment: @DennisSoemers I am trying to implement a customize softmax, so it would be a bit different than the normal one.

Comment: Can you share the code of this customized softmax? Just to make sure that it wouldn't happen to generate the same output as the original one? Or, alternatively, stick a print statement into your custom activation function's code. If you see those prints appearing, you know that your activation function is being called.

Comment: @DennisSoemers Ive added the function. I expect it to output `zeros` if you call `predict` method.

Comment: The problem is that the Tensorflow graph is not updated, regardless of the fact that the keras layer is updated. The change doesn't take into effect even recompiling with a new model. The only successful solution I have seen is https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis/blob/master/vis/utils/utils.py

``utils.apply_modifications`` and it is a bit of a clunky way.

Answer (score 5):

At the current state of things there's no official, clean way to do that. As pointed by @layser in the comments, the Tensorflow graph isn't being updated - which results in the lack of change in your output. One option is to use [`keras-vis' utils`](https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis/blob/master/vis/utils/utils.py#L95). My recommendation is to isolate that in your own `utils.py`, like so:

```
from vis.utils.utils import apply_modifications

def update_layer_activation(model, activation, index=-1):
    model.layers[index].activation = activation
    return apply_modifications(model)
```

Which would lead to a similar use:

```
model = update_layer_activation(model, custom_softmax)
```

If you follow the given link, you'll see what they do is quite simple: they save the `model` to a temporary path, then load it back and return, finally deleting the temp file.